# How to access Performance Insights tab in the chrome developer tools using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to access and click on elements of the Performance Insigts tab in google chrome using selenium (python), this command opens the console but replacing it with performance insights doesn't work.

Running this code works for the console but not for performance insights:

```
# Open with developer tools
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")

# Naviagate to tab and dock it at the bottom
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "devtools": {
        "preferences": {
        "panel-selectedTab": "\"console\"",
        "currentDockState": "\"bottom\"" 
        }
    }
})
```

What could be the solution if I want to access performance insights or say an extension that is visible in developer tools? How can I see the xpath elements, etc of these dev tools?